# Delete variables named in an "unconventional" way

Tags: kdb

A while ago I was reviewing some legacy code, and I incurred in the following issue: the developer create many variables starting with a dot (like `.variable1`), syntax reserved to define namesspaces. 
When quizzed about the use of that convention, he replied that essentially that was a way to create global variable within the scope of a function - what in Python you would achieve doing the following:

```
def define():
    global a
    a = 2

define()
print(a)
```

In `q`, that translated in something like this:

```
f1:{.b1:2;}
f2:{b1:2;}
f1[] / this creates a variable .b1, which you can use globally
f2[] / this creates a variable b1 within the scope of the function, not usable outside
```

While my preference would have been to create a global variable using a namespace (something like `f1:{.my_namespace.b1:2;}`), the code was doing its job without any issues.

The problem arises if I want to delete the global variable defined which starts with a dot (`.b1` in the case just described), given that approaches like

```
delete .b1 from `.
```

do not seem to work. All the references I was able to find (like [this](http://www.timestored.com/b/forums/topic/delete-variable-and-namespace/)) suggest that namespaces cannot be delete, which would imply these unproperly defined variable will stay there.

To be clear, the problem is not about how to delete variables from namespaces, but to delete those namespaces which are used as variables - if possible at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: The documentation is still valid as far as I'm aware - you can't delete a namespace from existence but you can delete all of its contents. ```delete from `.b1```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, you want to delete variables from a namespace. You can do this by running:

```
delete b1 from `.my_namespace
```

Which is also explained in the link you pasted.
What you can't do is actually delete the reference to `my_namespace`.

As a side note you can also set variables globally in the root namespace using the `set` keyword:

```
{`var set 2}[]
```

Which will let you avoid having to create single use namespaces.